# LazyInitializationException (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, hibernate

Изменил все фетч-тайпы на лези, так как мне не нужно выгружать полный список зависимостей, а достать только эту таблицу и начал ловить данный екзепшн. Уже многократно сталкивался с ним раньше, но сейчас не подходит ни один из вариантов, которые раньше решали эту проблему. 
Ниже приведен код, который удаляет сущность из базы: 
Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="place_type")
public class PlaceType {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private Long id;

@JoinColumn(name = "name")
private String name;

@JoinColumn(name="file")
private String file;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
        name="place_type_has_place",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "place_type_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "place_id")}
    )
private Set<Place> places = new HashSet<Place>();

// getters setters
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/list/remove/{id}")
public String removePlaceType(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    PlaceType placeType = placeTypeService.getById(id);
    placeTypeService.remove(placeType);
    return "redirect:/places/list.html?removePt=success";
}
```

Service:

```
    @Override
    public void remove(PlaceType placeType){
    Set<Place> place = placeType.getPlaces();
    Iterator<Place> placeList = place.iterator();
    while(placeList.hasNext()){
        placeList.next().getPlaceTypes().remove(placeType);
    }
    placeType.getPlaces().removeAll(place);
    placeTypeDao.remove(placeType.getId());
}
```

Ошибку выбивает в строчке:

```
Set<Place> place = placeType.getPlaces();
```

**Update:Ответ**

И так, многие убили немало времени на лейзи, но такого подвоха мало кто ожидал.
Как правило есть четыре пути избавления от этого лезиИнициализейшн. Для тех, кто пользуется спрингом и использует аннотации `@Transactional`, хочу сказать, что если вы пометили метод как транзакционный но все равно получаете данный екзепшн, проблема в параметрах метода. 
Если вы передаете в параметры Ентити, которые нужно обновить, удалить, сохранить или прочее, сессия открывается но (тут я не могу дать точный ответ что же происходит), jpa не воспринимает объект в параметре как ентити. 
Пример, как решить проблему именно в моем случае, изменить передачу целого объекта на передачу только его айди.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void remove(Long id){
PlaceType placeType = getById(id);
Set<Place> place = placeType.getPlaces();
Iterator<Place> placeList = place.iterator();
while(placeList.hasNext()){
    placeList.next().getPlaceTypes().remove(placeType);
}
placeType.getPlaces().removeAll(place);
placeTypeDao.remove(placeType.getId());
```

}

Теперь работает.

Comment: А метод placeTypeService.getById можно? видимо вам надо в нём инициализировать эту коллекцию, либо создать новый метод, который будет этим заниматься, если нельзя это сделать в getById.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте объявить сущность так:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
```

и не осуществлять чтение и удаление списка places, а удалять сразу `PlaceType`. Либо заменить `CascadeType.ALL` на `CascadeType.REMOVE`.

Если не сработает, попробуйте сделать `Hibernate.initialize(placeType.getPlaces())` перед обращением к `placeType.getPlaces()`, но к моменту вызова этого метода должна быть уже открытая сессия БД; вероятно, следует сделать это в `placeTypeDao`.

Comment: The attribute orphanRemoval is undefined for the annotation type ManyToMany

Comment: Атрибут orphanRemoval есть у javax.persistence.OneToMany начиная с версии Java EE 6. Видимо, у вас устаревшее приложение...

Comment: у меня седьмая джава. ну я не говорил, что в OneToMany нету, там же пишет, что в мени ту мени. Кстати нашел проблему, апдейтнул вопрос.